# How to apply Gradient to Line/Border of a shape in Powerpoint using C#?

Tags: office365, powerpoint, office-interop, office-addins, powerpoint-2016

In PowerPoint 2016 UI, it is possible to apply a gradient to the Border of a shape. The same however cannot be done using Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint in C#. I was able to apply a gradient to the shape but not to its border. Kindly advise how can it be achieved.

Comment: You can use a macro recorder available in Powerpoint to find the properties and methods to get the job done. See [Create a macro in PowerPoint](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/create-a-macro-in-powerpoint-5b07aff6-4dc9-462f-8fc9-66b4c5344e7e) for more information.

Comment: @EugeneAstafiev There's no macro recorder in PowerPoint any longer. According to your link, it's only available in 2010 and previous. Sometimes you can record things in Excel's macro recorder and get an idea of how to do the same thing in PPT, but in this case, it doesn't work.

Comment: {later} And after poking around the OM and IntelliSense, it doesn't look like line gradients are exposed to programmatic control.

Comment: I've checked the PowerPoint object model and didn't find anything for filling borders with gradients.

Comment: Same here. Not so much as a hint that it'd be possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree: there is no way that I can see to set a line gradient via the Interop assemblies. The clue for me was that you can't use the simple controls on the ribbon to do this, you need to use "Format Shape", and then you can set a bunch of stuff that also isn't available. This led me to think it was in the XML of the file, not accessible via the Object Model (OM) that the interop library provides.

I would recommend using a tool that can interact with the XML of the file itself, not just the application. It may also benefit you that you won't need to actually run PowerPoint, just edit the file. That can be faster.

Example tools are the Open XML SDK and something like Aspose.Slides, both of which edit the files directly.

MS-provided Interop libraries are dying. They've stopped distributing signed copies for the most recent versions, instead letting developers generate and sign their own. Office add-ins are the new thing right now, as they are cross-platform.

I hope this helps. Good luck.

Comment: Although this doesn't solve my problem in a direct way. I will try to implement a workaround with this. I accept this answer as a final word.

Answer (score 1):

The PowerPoint object model doesn't provide any property or method for setting up gradients in borders. The best what you could do is to fill a shape with a gradient color.

Comment: That might indeed be the trick:  Fill one shape with the desired gradient then add another shape atop it, slightly smaller, so that the original shape appears to be nothing but an outline of the second shape.

Comment: I thought about that as well, but it sounds awkward.

Comment: Too true. But when the awkward way is the only way, we do the awkward walk. ;-)